# Live Sorting or Fitering a Model using Textbox in Ember

Tags: javascript, ember.js, filtering

I was watching Ember screencasts & stumbled upon autocomplete-widget. I tried to implement something like that but it's not working it seems.

I am getting data using $.getJSON and I want to filter that using textbox.

Here's what I have tried,

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Model = Ember.Object.extend({

});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    redirect : function() {
        this.transitionTo('users');
    }
});

App.UsersController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({

    filteredContent : function() {
        var searchText = this.get('searchText'), regex = new RegExp(searchText, 'i');

        return this.get('model').filter(function(item) {
            return regex.test(item.name);
        });
    }.property('searchText', 'model')
});

App.Users = App.Model.extend({
    id : "",
    name : ""
});

App.UsersRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model : function() {
        return App.Users.findAll();
    },
    setupController : function(controller, model) {
        controller.set('model', model);
    }
});


App.Users.reopenClass({
    findAll : function() {
        return $.getJSON("user.php", function(data) {
            return data.map(function(row) {
                return App.Users.create(row);
            });
        });
    }
});

App.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource("users", {
        path : "/users"
    });
});
```

Here's my HTML,

```
       <body>
        <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="users">

            {{view Ember.TextField value=searchText}}
            <button {{action last}}>filter</button>
            <button {{action refresh}}>refresh</button>

             {{#each item in content }}
             <tr><td>
             <p> {{item.name}}</p>
             </td></tr>
            {{/each}}
        </script>

        <script type="text/x-handlebars">
            <h1>Application Template</h1>
            {{outlet}}
        </script>

    </body>
```

I am actually stuck on where should I make changes, I just need some pointers.

**Update**: Even though I am getting the expected outcome but I am getting

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'selectedIndex' of undefined
```

Any idea why I am getting this?

Comment: `App.controller` doesn't exists. What you want is `this.get`, and on your `TextField` you should use `valueBinding` instead of just value, otherwise the data binding won't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you are returning before the promise from $.getJSON has been fulfilled. Try changing your App.User.findAll so that it returns the results from inside the success callback.  So specifically, your findAll implementation might look like:

```
App.Users.reopenClass({
  findAll: function() {
    return $.getJSON("https://api.github.com/users/rjackson/repos", function(data) {
      return data.map(function(row) { return App.Users.create(row); });
    });
  }
});
```

Also, I do not believe that you need to manually create the ArrayProxy object. Return an array from your routes model hook should suffice.

I made some additional tweaks to your original (including using a sample JSON endpoint) here: http://jsbin.com/oWUBeMu/3/edit

**Updated: 2013/08/30**

The selectedIndex error is being caused by the HTML comments in your 'users' template. Handlebars comments should be {{! }} or {{!-- --}}. The html comments were causing some bizare escaping when parsing the template that caused it not to be able to bind to the properties properly.